# Joining to another table on fields other than its primary key

Tags: mysql, sql, django, django-models

Suppose I have `Table_A`, and I want to join it to `Table_B` on two fields they both have, `school_id`, and `type_id`.  In SQL this looks like:

```
SELECT whatever
FROM Table_A
INNER JOIN Table_B 
 ON (Table_A.school_id = Table_B.school_id 
     AND Table_A.type_id = Table_B.type_id)
```

As far as I understand, Django does its joining through Foreign/Primary keys defined in the models.  So if you were to do `A.objects.filter(B__field2="stuff")` it would implicitly be joining on `A.B_id = B.id` in addition to putting the `Table_B.field2=stuff` in the `WHERE` clause.  Is there a way to instead join on keys of my choosing, as in the above SQL query?

Comment: Is the `A.B_id=B.id` incorrect for some reason?

Comment: I don't want to limit it in that way..  I want to allow `Table_A` to join to `Table_B` even if `Table_A` isn't its child

Comment: Are you sure it's the best (or only) way to solve your task? Can you show your models and describe the result you want to get?

Answer (score 0):

If it's still valid to express your query in this form:

```
SELECT whatever FROM Table_A, Table_B WHERE (Table_A.school_id = Table_B.school_id 
     AND Table_A.type_id = Table_B.type_id)
```

(which would be equivalent to your example above...) then it's possible to do this via the Django ORM and the [extra](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/querysets/#extra) clause, eg:

```
TableA.objects.extra(
    tables=['myapp_tableb',],
    where=['myapp_tablea.school_id=myapp_tableb.school_id',
           'myapp_tablea.type_id=myapp_tableb.type_id']
)
```

I realise there are probably some kinds of complex joins that you could do in SQL which won't lend themselves to this.

The ugly part is you have to use your real SQL table names rather than Django model names, it's a bit closer to raw SQL... but you do get back a regular Django QuerySet object.